# Why does my code not fill a table in database?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, sql-insert

The following code works:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public  class ItemGroupInputFromConsole extends Parser{

public ItemGroupInputFromConsole() {

}
@Override
public void visit(ItemGroup itemGroup) throws SQLException{
    System.out.println("ItemGroup String id, String group_name");
    super.readRawInput();
    String[] rawinput = super.getRawInput();
    itemGroup.setId(rawinput[0]);
    itemGroup.setGroup_name(rawinput[1]);
    String SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO \"Item_Group\"(id,group_name) "
            + "VALUES(?,?)";



    PreparedStatement pstmt = super.connection.prepareStatement(SQLinsert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    pstmt.setString(1, itemGroup.getId());
    pstmt.setString(2, itemGroup.getGroup_name());

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}
```

When I try almost similar code it produces a runtime error:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class UserInputFromConsole extends Parser {

public UserInputFromConsole(){

}
@Override
public void visit(User user) throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("User String id, String name, int age, String adress, int account,    String bad_behaviour");
    super.readRawInput();
    String[] rawinput = super.getRawInput();
    user.setId(rawinput[0]);
    user.setName(rawinput[1]);
    user.setAge(rawinput[2]);
    user.setAdress(rawinput[3]);
    user.setAccount(rawinput[4]);
    user.setBad_behaviour(rawinput[5]);
    String SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO user(id,name,age,adress,account,bad_bahaviour) "
            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";


    PreparedStatement pstmt = super.connection.prepareStatement(SQLinsert, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

    pstmt.setString(1, user.getId());
    pstmt.setString(2, user.getName());
    pstmt.setString(3, user.getAge());
    pstmt.setString(4, user.getAdress());
    pstmt.setString(5, user.getAccount());
    pstmt.setString(6, user.getBad_behaviour());

    pstmt.executeUpdate();
}}
```

The error is on the line pstmt.executeUpdate(); in the second code. The first code works, the second produces an error.
Where do I have to debug, in order to find this error?
Maybe in the database?

Why is this happening?
The error is syntax error in user but the first one is on line with
pstmt.executeUpdate().

Error I get:
[image]

Comment: What is the **exact** error you get?

Comment: syntax error at or near "user"

Comment: there is a photo

Comment: Unrelated, but: columns named `id` are usually associated with `integer` (or `bigint`) values - if that is the case, then you should pass an integer as a String value. `pstmt.setInt(1, user.getId())` would be more appropriate then.

Answer (score 3):

`user` is a reserved keyword, you need to use double quotes - or better find a different name:

```java
String SQLinsert = "INSERT INTO \"user\" (id,name,age,adress,account,bad_bahaviour) "
            + "VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```